# Django Create User from Azure Graph AD

Tags: python, django, azure

*My question is regarding the practice of creating/saving users to the Django app when users are logging through an external API like Azure AD.*

I am following the [Azure AD Django project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tutorial-step=3) example.

In a vanilla Django project, in order to create a new user you would add this new person to the `User` model that Django creates for you. See documentation: [Creating Users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/)

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

# At this point, user is a User object that has already been saved
# to the database. You can continue to change its attributes
# if you want to change other fields.
>>> user.last_name = 'Lennon'
>>> user.save()
```

However, if your app is using something similar to Azure AD Graph, then the user is logging using their Microsoft credentials (e.g. email/password) and a user is obtained from the request object. Here is an example of what you may obtain

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'> <Response [200]>
```

with data

```
{'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity', 
    'displayName': 'Jon Doe', 'surname': 'Doe', 'givenName': 'Jon', 
    'id': '8431c9c085f05a72', 'userPrincipalName': 'jondoe@hotmail.com', 
    'businessPhones': [], 'jobTitle': None, 'mail': None, 'mobilePhone': None, 
    'officeLocation': None, 'preferredLanguage': None}
```

With this given data is it good practice to then create a new user in Django similar to the example above? If so, the what data should be saved to this model? Does the password matter for this new `User` since they are logging in through an external service? Also, how should I associate the person logging in through Azure AD with the Django `User` model object?

*Basically, I am wondering what current practices or references exist for this type of project.*

Comment: Both azure AD packages that I found after a quick search will create entries in the users table for you. https://pypi.org/project/django-azure-ad-auth/ https://pypi.org/project/django-microsoft-auth/

Comment: Setting AAD_USER_CREATION as `True` and create user by referring to https://github.com/leibowitz/django-azure-ad-auth/blob/master/azure_ad_auth/backends.py#L89. You need to provide new password by yourself. The password of Azure AD user won't be returned in the Azure AD token.

Comment: Hi @Jon, any updates?

Comment: @AllenWu Sorry for the late response, I didn't see your last message. I ended up reading the code from the `django-azure-ad-auth` and creating something similar. My app saves users, but doesn't require a password for them since authentication is taken care of by Azure AD. The only annoying part was the HTTPS requirement.